# AWS Sagemaker custom template crowd-form , add Skip button and see the number of the remining tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I want to add an Skip button to my form-crowd and receive the number of remaining tasks for the worker to see.

I create a custom crowd-form template for Sagemaker and add the preProcess and postProcess lambda functions. Everything is working fine but I want to add a skip button that will skip the evaluation and also see the numbers of remining/total tasks, the event variable that is receive in my preProcess function doesn't contain any information about how many json object I have in my manifest file.

How can I create a custom endpoint or event to add the skip functionality and receive the numbers of task in the worker window ?